# Plotting graph edge density with R

Tags: r, graph, plot, scatter-plot

I'm plotting the vertex degree (# of incident edges) of the graph `g`.

```
deg <- degree(g, v=V(g), mode = c("in"), loops = TRUE)  
histdata <- hist( deg, breaks=1000, plot=FALSE )
plot(histdata$count, log="xy", type="p", col="blue", bg = "blue", pch=20,
        xlim=c(1,max(deg)),
        ylim=c(1,max(histdata$count)),
        ylab="Frequency", xlab="Degree")
```

This code plots **this [scatterplot](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/1038/scatter.png)**, 
[image]

which is very close to what I need but has a few issues:

1) the x labels are wrong, as they don't represent the degrees but the histogram breaks.

2) the axis bars are messy. How can I remove the empty ones?

3) how can I plot a **regression line**? I tried with `abline` and `lm(histdata$mids~histdata$count)` but nothing gets plotted.

Thanks for any hint!

**UPDATE**: this plot is probably plain wrong. See http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/idl/papers/ranking/ranking.html

Comment: For # 3 I would have guessed abline(coef(lm(...))).

Comment: For #1: do you want different locations for ticmarks or just different labels for the default locations?  If the former, set plot() to suppress the axis(partially) and use mtext(). If the latter, try plotting a different variable first with plot(...,t="n") and then plot your data with axes=F.   Or, take a look at ggplot or lattice, which are more flexible in many ways.